# MOSFET and clamp on I2C interface lines as level tranlastor

Tags: mosfet, i2c, level-translation

I'm trying to understand what's going on in this circuit:

[image]

I understand the master direction. I2C lines usually are pulled up by default, so when the line is high or idle, the GS voltage < 0.7V, which means the mosfet is off. With it off, the Drain is going to be pulled up thanks to the 5V and clamped.

Master drives low, GS > 4.5V, Mosfet on, Source pulls Drain down. All fine.

What I'm confused about: This is a bidirectional bus. The slave (right hand side) is also capable of pulling the data line low (sometimes the clock too). If the slave pulls what essentially is the drain of the mosfet down while the mosfet is off (since the master side is high) then the pulldown on the slave side won't be seen by the master? Or am I missing something here?

What's the advantage of this over a standard boring level translator IC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an excellent application note by nxp that explains this clever level translation circuit. 
See section 2.3 of http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/interface/pdf/an97055.pdf

Since the least understood part is how a low goes from the right (higher Vdd) to the left (lower Vdd), I'll explain that first.

Basically when the right hand side (slave in this case) goes low, the parasitic diode pulls the left side down enough that Vgs > Vth, so the mosfet becomes conducting and the left side can be pulled down to the same low voltage as the right side via the mosfet's channel (so not just down to a diode's drop).

That last detail is what makes the circuit clever.  It is easy to forget that a mosfet can conduct both ways when turned on, after realizing that it is the parasitic diode that will help turn it on.

What follows is just an excerpt of the aforementioned application note, as a reference.

> For the level shift operation three states has to be considered:
>
> • State 1. No device is pulling down the bus line and the bus line of
>   the “Lower voltage” section is pulled up by its pull-up resistors Rp
>   to 3.3 V. The gate and the source of the MOS-FET are both at 3.3 V, so
>   its VGS is below the threshold voltage and the MOS-FET is not
>   conducting. This allows that the bus line at the “Higher voltage”
>   section is pulled up by its pull-up resistor Rp to 5V. So the bus
>   lines of both sections are HIGH, but at a different voltage level.
>
> • State 2. A 3.3 V device pulls down the bus line to a LOW level. The
>   source of the MOS-FET becomes also LOW, while the gate stay at 3.3 V.
>   The V rises above the threshold and the MOS-FET becomes conducting.
>   Now the bus line of the “Higher voltage” section is also pulled down
>   to a LOW level by the 3.3V device via the conducting MOS-FET. So the
>   bus lines of both sections become LOW at the same voltage level.
>
> • State 3. A 5 V device pulls down the bus line to a LOW level. Via
>   the drain-substrate diode of the MOS- FET the “Lower voltage” section
>   is in first instance pulled down until V passes the threshold and the
>   GS MOS-FET becomes conducting. Now the bus line of the “Lower voltage”
>   section is further pulled down to a LOW level by the 5 V device via
>   the conducting MOS-FET. So the bus lines of both sections become LOW
>   at the same voltage level.
>
> The three states show that the logic levels are transferred in both
>   directions of the bus system, independent of the driving section.

Some advantages of using this single transistor design are cost, simplicity, and least dependence on a specific vendor.  Bidirectional transmission gates will get you a bit of extra speed, but in the case of I2C it would most likely be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

There should be another set of pull-up resistors on the master side (left hand side).  If the slave (right hand side) pulls the line down, then the MOSFET body diode will conduct.  The line on the left hand side of the MOSFET will be pulled down through the MOSFET body diode.

**Edit:**  I don't think that there is advantage to this method, other than lower cost.  By the way, which standard level translator ICs have bored you so?

Comment: Oh, I see, so that's what that little diode in the symbol is for! :P Seriously though, missed that. Thanks.